# How to identify Delphi StringList object is created or not

Tags: delphi, tstringlist

I have declared variable of TStringList in private section. In a button click event I want to access that TStringList object.

```
sVariable:= TStringList.Create;
sVariable.add('Test1');
```

Now whenever i click on that button each time its newly created and memory is allocated to that variable. Is there any property/function using which we can determine object is created for that variable or not and it will not give the access violation error also?

Comment: Careful, all of the answers are forgetting to initialize variable/field and instead reliyng on implicit initialization.

Comment: +1 for access **voila**tion indeed :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if not Assigned(sVariable) then
  sVariable:= TStringList.Create;
sVariable.add('Test1');
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way to approach it, expanding on David's answer, is through a property with a read method.

```
TMyForm = class (TForm)
private
  FStrList : TStringList;
public
  property StrList : TStringList read GetStrList;
  destructor Destroy; override;
end;

implementation

function TMyForm.GetStrList : TStringList;
begin
  if not Assigned(FStrList) then
    FStrList := TStringList.Create;
  Result := FStrList;
end;

destructor TMyForm.Destroy;
begin
  FStrList.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Edit: Added the Free call in an overridden destructor.

Comment: This is the better approach if the list may be used from more than one part of the code, but probably overkill if it is only to be accessed in one place.